How can I exclude B for question 22 for the HSK6 Standard Course Workbook (ch. 33)?


处理问题必须 [blank]， 不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到 [blank] 的；不仅要看到局部的，还要看到全局的；不仅要了解本国 [blank]，还要了解世界 [blank]；不仅要看到世界发展对本国的影响，还要看到本国发展对世界的影响。
A 左顾右盼 大众 文化 时势
B 高瞻远瞩 外界 要求 大局
C 一往直前 后来 情形 所需
D 瞻前顾后 长远 国情 局势
HSK6 Standard Course Workbook (下册, ch.32, Q22)

This is a fill-in-the-blank exercise; I chose B, but the correct answer is D (in bold).  I cannot figure out the justification as to how to exclude B.
I preferred 长远 over 外界 (as 长远 pairs better with 眼前), and 国情 over 要求, but 大局 seems better than 局势 for a global perspective.  I had to look up 高瞻远瞩 and 瞻前顾后, and they both seem plausible.
Question: How can I exclude B for question 22 for the HSK6 Standard Course Workbook (ch. 33)?
Usually there's a concrete, identifiable mismatch, but here I cannot find it.

「眼前」形容抽象的事物（比如这里的「处理问题」）的时候，其意思是「现在」，即时间上的概念，与此相对应的应该是「后来」或者「长远」，所以「外界」不合适。否则，只能将「眼前」按照「局部」去理解了，这样就和第二个并列重复了

“瞻前顾后”不是一个正确的用法。我认为出题不对。

眼前只能对长远，别的都不对。不能是

@PdotWang +1, 瞻前顾后 最原始的用法，應該是周密思考；問題是 現在基本都會要求別人: 做事 *不要* 瞻前顧後

i.e. https://www.cheers.com.tw/article/article.action?id=5065294  人生不要瞻前顧後，因為選擇是包裹，裡面一定有好的、也有壞的

ie2. https://www.163.com/dy/article/FUS0KF8805429MRP.html 怎么戒掉做事犹豫不决、瞻前顾后的 *缺点* ...

I think the main problem with the answer lies in 瞻前顾后
Although the original meaning of 瞻前顾后 is to describe careful consideration before doing something (praise)
形容做事前考虑周密慎重(褒)
But in fact in today's China/Taiwan, it means too much worry and indecisiveness (derogatory)
顾虑太多，犹豫不决(貶)

I will choose these answer:


B高瞻远瞩, D.长远 D.国情 [B.大局|D.局势]


Either [B.大局] or [D.局势] seems to be fine here.

I would not choose [B.外界], because:



不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到 [B.外界] 的；

外界 cannot be compared with 眼前, it would be better to use 长远 here

And, don't choose [B.要求], because


不仅要看到局部的，还要看到全局的；不仅要了解本国 [B.要求] ，

This is NOT a negotiation and a country should NOT be making any demands here.
General speaking, I don't agree with the 1st answer of D. but the others look fine.

The above only represent personal views and ideas

Question:-How can I exclude B?
Let's put the two options side-by-side:-
Answer B:-
处理问题必须(高瞻远瞩)， 不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到(外界)的.
When dealing with problems must (be far-sighted), not only must we see what is in front of us, (i.e. the present), but also look at (the external environment).
Answer D:-
处理问题必须(瞻前顾后)， 不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到(长远)的.
When dealing with problems must (consider the future and the past), not only must we see what is in front of us, (i.e. the present), but also look at (the long-term).
My view is that without even considering whether 国情, 局势 in (A) is more or less suitable than 要求, 大局 in (B), just judging from the side-by-side comparison, (D) is already more suitable because the opening sentence in the passage says, i.e.:-
"处理问题必须 [blank]， 不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到 [blank] 的" is talking about temporal dimensions / relating to time, i.e. "眼前的", (the present), thus the missing words / phrases before and after "眼前的" should be related to "time" as well, because when you consider the "present", you must also consider the "future and the past" (瞻前顾后), and the "long term", (长远的), as could be seen in option (D):-
--- "...瞻前顾后", (look forward and backward, i.e. "future and the past");
--- "...眼前的", (in front of us, i.e. "the present");
--- "...长远的", ("long term").
But in Option (B), we have:-
--- "高瞻远瞩", ("be far-sighted");
--- "...眼前的", (in front of us, i.e. the "present");
--- "...外界的, ("the external environment").
Thus in (B), there is a diametrical shift from the time dimensions, ("be far-sighted" and "the present"), to an incongruent spatial dimension, ("the external environment")
"瞻前顾后", "眼前的" and "长远的" therefore has the semantic consistency which "高瞻远瞩", "眼前的" and"外界的" lacks, and thus a better choice.


How can I exclude B for question 22

For the first blank, both B and D would do.
For the second blank, there must be a contrast with 眼前的, which is: 长远的
Thus B is eliminated.

Let's start by examining the part of the question without the blanks first:

不仅要看到局部的，还要看到全局的 …… 不仅要看到世界发展对本国的影响，还要看到本国发展对世界的影响。
We must not only consider the local perspective but also the global one …… we should recognize not only the impact of global development on our country but also the influence of our country's development on the world.

We can see that the objects (as in the Subject-Verb-Object pattern) in the previous and following clauses have opposite meanings. Therefore, we should also fill in opposite words for different objects within the same clause.
Back to the question, option D is the most likely choice, as "本国[国情]" and "国际[局势]" are direct opposites within the same clause.
However, I think "瞻前顾后" is an ambiguous choice for the first blank, as it could also be used to describe someone who is overly cautious and indecisive. Some better alternatives are:

通观全局 (tōng guān quán jú): look at the big picture.
面面俱到 (miàn miàn jù dào): to do everything necessary to be sure that something is successful.


Both B. 高瞻远瞩 (with good foresight) and D. 瞻前顾后 (consider the past and the future) are suitable
D. 眼前的(short-term) matches 长远的(long-term)
B. 眼前的(short-term) doesn't match 外界的 (outside)
D. 本国国情(domestic situration) matches 世界局势 (international situration)
B. 要求(need) doesn't match 大局 (the big picture)
B. 外界的 (outside) should match 內部的 (inside)
B. 要求(need) should match 需要 (need)
B. 大局 (the big picture) should match 局部 (part of the picture)

Use my own words, I would have the blanks filled as below:
处理问题必须 [顧及全面]， 不仅要看到眼前的(1)，还要看到 [長遠] 的(2)；不仅要看到局部的(1)，还要看到全局的(2)；不仅要了解本国 [情勢](1)，还要了解世界 [局勢](2)；不仅要看到世界发展对本国的影响(1)，还要看到本国发展对世界的影响(2)。
(1) = near sight or locally/domestically; (2) = far sight or globally/worldly
IMO, the paragraph emphasizes that "one must be prudent/look around in dealing with problems". So, although 瞻前顾后 isn't the best idiom to be the answer, but between the given two, it nevertheless is the correct choice.

高瞻远瞩 - I) look far ahead and aim high; II) be farsighted (the idiom emphasizes forward-looking)

瞻前顾后 - I) look ahead and behind (the idiom means be look around and prudent); II) be overcautious and indecisive (see note below)


Note: This explanation/implication makes this idiom an unwise/unfit choice to be the main assertion of the content. I think "顧及全面(take into account all aspects)" sounds better.

If you look at the structure of the whole sentence, the author keeps repeating a pattern which says you have to look at both sides of many things. The first blank is just the summary of such idea. So you have to use a word to represent such idea in the first blank.
A.左顾右盼 (looking left and right) is possible but it is a derogatory word.
B.高瞻远瞩 (looking long term) only has one meaning.
C.一往直前 (keep going forward) also has only one meaning.
D.瞻前顾后 (looking front and back) is also possible. It is also a derogatory word.
You can easily exclude B and C from the first blank. A and D are both derogatory word in modern Chinese unless this is some old Chinese. So this question is just wrong. The sentence sounds very weird with D unless someone argues it is some old usage.

一个选择D选项的技巧，简单快捷：
观察下面的加粗重点词汇

不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到 [blank] 的；不仅要看到局部的，还要看到全局的；不仅要了解本国 [blank]，还要了解世界 [blank]；不仅要看到世界发展对本国的影响，还要看到本国发展对世界的影响。

如果你知道点哲学的话(我是理科专业，学校没教哲学，自己学的)，很明显可以看出来，他们有相对统一规律。
所以，在不仅要看到眼前的，还要看到 [blank] 的， 中，眼前的，即离现在很近很近的一个时间(点)，与之相对应的是将来或未来，离现在很长远的一个时间(点)。

Basically I agree with your choices. In addition, 高瞻远瞩 seems better than 瞻前顾后, because people often use 不要瞻前顾后 nowadays, just like other answers say.
As for 大局 I have some personal thoughts. 世界大局 is not appropriate since 大局 usually used for situations inside the country. You can see news titles 积极融入国家发展大局，社会大局和谐稳定. 了解xx大局 is also abnormal here, more often combination is 认识大局. So I prefer the combination 世界局势.
